# Load image from URI into Button in Xamarin.Forms using FFImageLoading

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, ffimageloading

Is there any way to load `Image` into Xamarin.Forms `Button` from URL?
It seems that button itself only support `FileImageSource`.

Sure, I can download image and then manually put it into `Button`, but I hope someone has done this already in reusable fashion :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add Tap gesture on a image instead of button
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/gestures/tap/

Comment: That's what we end up doing :)

Answer (score 1):

Try putting Image control inside a frame control which will give a better view like button with drop shadow if you prefer. Plus use the Tapgesture